# How to preview LazyPagingItems/Paging 3 Library in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list

I think the title says it all.

`LazyPagingItems` constructor is internal. I can't pass `LazyPagingItems` as parameter in Preview Composable, let alone passing sample data. But I want to show preview of my composable, how should I do this?

```
@Composable
fun MainUi(users: LazyPagingItems<User>) {
    Scaffold {
        LazyColumn() {
            items(users) {
                // Rest of the code..
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun Preview() {
    DefaultTheme {
        MainUi(users = ) // How to pass sample data here?
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe there's not way to do that now, since LazyPagingItems is based on LaunchedEffect and that seems not to cooperate with Preview

Answer (score 20):

You can use `PagingData.empty()` or `PagingData.from(List<T>)`, like this:

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun Preview() {
    DefaultTheme {
        MainUi(users = flowOf(PagingData.from(listOf(User(..)))).collectAsLazyPagingItems()
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if the items are shown in the preview, but at least you get to render it...

Comment: Unfortunately they are not shown in a preview

Comment: Actually I have filled an issue in Google Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/194544557). I can get it to build now but the list isn't shown.

Comment: Is it at least planned to be fixed in the future? I see the issue tracker doesn't answer at all

Comment: They said it's planning for Q2/Q3 2023. Let's hope it won't get magically marked as fixed, again.

Answer (score 3):

I have not tried this, but there is an example of previewing LazyPagingItems in the paging repository

https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/paging/paging-compose/src/androidTest/java/androidx/paging/compose/LazyPagingItemsPreviewTest.kt

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
@Preview
@Composable
fun PagingPreview() {
    val data = List(50) { it }
    val flow = MutableStateFlow(PagingData.from(data))
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalInspectionMode provides true,
    ) {
        // Use StandardTestDispatcher so we don't start collecting on PagingData
        val lazyPagingItems = flow.collectAsLazyPagingItems(StandardTestDispatcher())
        LazyColumn(Modifier.height(500.dp)) {
            items(count = lazyPagingItems.itemCount) { index ->
                val item = lazyPagingItems[index]
                Spacer(Modifier.height(50.dp).fillParentMaxWidth().testTag("$item"))
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
@Preview
@Composable
fun EmptyPreview() {
    val data = emptyList<Int>()
    val flow = MutableStateFlow(PagingData.from(data))
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalInspectionMode provides true,
    ) {
        // Use StandardTestDispatcher so we don't start collecting on PagingData
        val lazyPagingItems = flow.collectAsLazyPagingItems(StandardTestDispatcher())
        LazyColumn(Modifier.height(500.dp)) {
            items(count = lazyPagingItems.itemCount) { index ->
                val item = lazyPagingItems[index]
                Spacer(Modifier.height(50.dp).fillParentMaxWidth().testTag("$item"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked fine for me. Also it looks like that the StandardTestDispatcher is not needed, as well as the CompositionLocalProvider.

Comment: I think the sample moved here:

https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/paging/paging-compose/samples/src/main/java/androidx/paging/compose/samples/PagingPreviewSample.kt

Answer (score 2):

this is how you can also handle and show page states the page states. refresh, append, prepend.

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun ScreenContentPreview() {
    ScreenContent(
        Modifier,
        "One Free ticket",
        pageState =
        flowOf(
            PagingData.from(
                listOf(*YOUR_LIST_OF_OBJECT*
                ),
                sourceLoadStates =
                LoadStates(
                    refresh = LoadState.NotLoading(false),
                    append = LoadState.NotLoading(false),
                    prepend = LoadState.NotLoading(false),
                ),
            ),
        ).collectAsLazyPagingItems(),
    )
}
```

hope this help to someone.